# high voltage cable in attic has damaged sheath cover

Tags: electrical

I was up in my attic doing a repair.  I noticed the main high voltage line sheath has been damaged on the outside.  You can see the red copper inside.  It is covered by some clear lacquer.  The damage is still around the 4 inch section. The sheath looks to be made of some sort of black tarp material.

What i need to know is how to get it repaired.  Can it be retaped to put a new cover or comperly replaced.  It is the main lihe to my ac going to the box.

The house was built in 61.  Dont know long it was damaged.  It is sitting in top of a floor stud.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A photo would be helpful here.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the cable, both of the damaged section and of an intact length?

Comment: If it's insulation chewed by small animals, you'd do well to check the entire run of the wire as well.

Comment: First off:  don't touch the thing while it's live.  You'll need the local electrical utility or a licensed electrician to cut power outside the house before doing anything with this feed.

Comment: It's not worth risking your life to fix this. Hire a qualified electrician. If they think it's repairable then great but do watch out for guys that are in a hurry to perform a costly replacement. If 3 electricians say that replacement is the only option then that is your answer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- the description is ambiguous, but I suspect that it is just the feed for the air conditioner, which can be turned off at the panel... no POCO required.